# Finding the number of sentences or lines in a paragraph in order to re-size its borders?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am having trouble with a jQuery function that I have created for my news page.
What I would like to be able to do is find the number of rows/lines/sentences in an amount of text ( a few paragraphs with 
 break lines in between them).
The reason I need this is to be able to re-size a text area's borders as to allow the rest of the text to be read.
The user is presented with a summary paragraph of a certain size and then if they would like to read more they click a button and the text area opens up to reveal the rest of the text.
I need the number of rows as to multiply that by the font-size so that I can fit all of the text into the new text-area, how can I find this number(the number of rows/lines in a paragraph)?

Code is at : http://jsfiddle.net/3nmhu/1/ or below
-Click the 'V' to the bottom-right of the text to expand the text area. 
-Click the 'A' to the bottom-right of the text to contract the text area.

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.read_less').hide();
    $('.read_more').click(function(){   
    //confirm($(this).parent().text().length/12);   
    $('.news_item').fadeOut('slow');
    $(this).parents().fadeIn('slow');
    $(this).hide(); 
    $('.read_less').show('slow');
    $(this).parent().animate({height:($(this).parent().text().length/50) *20 + 'px',width:'655px'},'slow');
    //$('.bars2').show('slow');
    //$('.bars').animate({width:'255px'},'slow');
    //$('.bars2').animate({width:'255px'},'slow');


    });
    $('.read_less').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().animate({height:'110px',width:'464px'},'slow');
    $('.news_item').fadeIn('slow');
    $('.read_less').hide(); 
    $('.read_more').show();

    });
});
```

I want to create these news items so that each will be able to define it's own expansion space that allows just the text to be read and for the text to fit in the text area snugly and my solution needs the number of lines.However I am unsure how to find this number.
Moreover, if you have a better suggestion as to how I could remedy my error and help me to solve the task at hand it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not let word-wrapping do it was designed to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've realized that finding the number of lines is a roundabout way of just setting the expanded box to a .css('height','auto'); upon click of the read more button.
Thanks for all the help to those who tried.

Answer (score 2):

One approach could be to take out your div's `offsetHeight` and divide it by it's `line-height`. This would give you the number of lines.

Or you can use [`getClientRects()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.getClientRects) function of javascript, that I think surely does the exact thing. This function just converts every line into a rectangle then we can just get its `length` and get the number of lines.

Comment: Very good answer. To expand on it, you could also use the new CSS3 properties that truncate text.

Comment: @mattcurtis which property?

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I am a beginner jQuery programmer and am unsure of my code(it probably will make no sense) but here is what I've tried based on your response. Thanks again. 

I've tried changing: 

'$(this).parent().animate({height:($(this).parent().text().length/50) *20 + 'px',width:'655px'},'slow');' to

$(this).parent().animate({height:($(this).parent().getClientRects().length) *20 +'px',width:'655px'},'slow');

Comment: However it did not work. I have also tried..

$(this).parent().animate({height:($(this).offsetHeight/$(this).parent().css('line-Height') *20 + 'px',width:'655px'},'slow');

Although it isn't producing a result. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: change `line-Height` to `line-height`.

Comment: @Delrog If his answer solved your problem you should mark it as the answer.

Comment: I would, however my code is still not being accepted?


$(this).parent().animate({height:($(this).offsetHeight/$(this).parent().css('lin‌​e-height') *20 + 'px',width:'655px'},'slow');

Comment: Try this:
`$(this).parent().animate({height:($(this).parent().offsetHeight/$(this).parent().css('lin‌​‌​e-height') *20 + 'px',width:'655px'},'slow');` and please make a jsFiddle.

Comment: The code won't even run, I get a coding syntax error in Dreamweaver ( red bar). I did make a jsFiddle up above.